# Error "type 'Future<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'StreamTransformer<List<String>, List<String>>'"

Tags: dart, stream, flutter, rxdart, bloc

I am getting an error "type 'Future' is not a subtype of type 'StreamTransformer, List>" in my BLOC".

This is the structure of my app:
A BLOC (namely, reports_bloc).
A Repository (namely, repository).
An API Provider (namely, api_provider).

In detail, The API Provider file fetches the data online. The Repository file makes ready the data from API Provider (actually, I am also using DB, the reason why I choose to have a Repository file). The BLOC is meant to get data from Repository and add it to Stream and Sink accordingly. I believe the issue is in the BLOC (I am probably getting things wrong here as regards to adding to Stream and "Sinking" data).

The code is here:

```
 //reports_bloc.dart
  import 'package:rxdart/rxdart.dart';
  import '../resources/repository.dart';

  class ReportsBloc  {
    final _repository = Repository();
    final _allReports = PublishSubject<List<dynamic>>();

    Observable<List<dynamic>> allReports;  

    ReportsBloc(){
      allReports = _allReports.stream.transform(fetchAllReports());
    }

    fetchAllReports() async{
      var reports = await _repository.fetchAllReports();
       _allReports.sink.add(reports);
    }

    dispose() {
     _allReports.close();
    }
  }



  //repository.dart
  import 'dart:async';
  import 'api_provider.dart';

  class Repository {

    ApiProvider apiProvider = ApiProvider();

    Future<List<dynamic>> fetchAllReports(){
      var response =  apiProvider.getAllReports();
      return response;
    }  
  }


  //api_provider.dart
  Future<List<dynamic>> getAllReports() async {
    List<dynamic> reports = [];

    final response = await http.get("$_root$_getAllReports");
    var result = json.decode(response.body); 

    for(var i = 0; i < result.length; i++){
      reports.add(result[i]);
      print(reports[i]['type']);
    }

    return reports;
   }
```

The Expected result is to be able to add data from the Repository and sink it.

Answer (score 0):

I have been able to fix this error. Simply put, what I did is redefining ReportsBloc class's constructor as below:

```
ReportsBloc(){
  fetchAllReports();
  allReports = _allReports.stream;
}
```

However, I am not really sure if this is a good practice, but it fixed my issue anyway.

Comment: You could directly define the all reports to the stream result.

Comment: `Observable<List<dynamic>> allReports = _allReports.stream;`

Comment: Then instead of fetching all reports in constructor. Do it in the widgets `initState` or if your using `onGenerateRoute` in the `router` generator before loading the route;